# Application_End fired in Debug Session after Code Rebuild - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express

I have a problem when debugging my code after making a code change.

Application_End is being fired every time I have made a code change. The application starts again but the session state has been lost! If I debug the application again it is fine - it does not restart or lose session!

This error only occurs while debugging locally (VS2013) using IIS Express 8. I have published to my machines IIS and there are no runtime problems. This is confirmed by viewing the event logs.

I can also run without debug in VS2013 after rebuilding the code without problem.

Here is the stack when it fails

```
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.InvokeMethodWithAssert(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, int paramCount, object eventSource, System.EventArgs eventArgs)   Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ProcessSpecialRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, int paramCount, object eventSource, System.EventArgs eventArgs, System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState session)  Unknown
>   System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.FireApplicationOnEnd() Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.Dispose()  Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.Dispose() Unknown
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ReleaseResourcesAndUnloadAppDomain(object state)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

Can anybody help me understand why this is happening?

**EDIT**
I have found this only occurs when the Rebuild option is taken *or* the F5 is taken after code change. It is fine when any of the Build options are taken followed by F5.

F5 must be doing a Rebuild and entering a race condition. The app must be started, in parallel the compile must occur causing the app to end then start again because the dependant files have changed since the app originally started.

This is just instinct though - can anybody confirm and put my mind at rest?

**EDIT 2**
I need to provide clarity.

Steps taken to fire application_end and lose session:
With the application NOT running - no IIS Express worker process

- Make a code change
- Place a breakpoint in Global.asax.cs application_start and application_end methods
- Press F5
  During loading of first page:

  - Application_start is hit - good and normal
  - Application_end is hit - bad not normal
  - Application_start is hit again

I would not expect the application to end without recognised triggers such as changing web.config while the application is running. To be clear, my application is making no changes to any code or config files before it ends.

What I have found is I can prevent this happening by building *before* pressing F5. Conversely if I rebuild before F5 it fails. So to be clear:

With app NOT running - no worker processes:

- Code change + F5 = failure
- Code change + build + F5 = success
- Code change + rebuild + F5 = failure

I would not expect F5 after a code change to fail if IIS is not running before F5 is pressed. I realise the assemblies are changed during the compile and this would cause the app pool to recycle *if IIS is up*, but it isn't.

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: it is pretty obvious that if you have a code change... the project gets unlodaded, compiled and run from the beggining again.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear - when you say making a code change when debugging, do you mean using the Edit and Continue feature? So you're making changes to the code while in a debug session?

Either way I would have thought this is expected behaviour. If you change your code, the application would be unloaded and re-loaded which would naturally cause your session state to be lost. What behaviour were you expecting to see? Has it been behaving differently until now?

You can see from this line of your stack trace that the AppDomain is being unloaded:

`System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ReleaseResourcesAndUnloadAppDomain(object state)`

Comment: Code change is made then I attempt debug F5. I wouldn't expect the app to end unless the usual triggers occurs such as: pool recycling; dependant file changes etc. I could understand it if I recompiled files when the application is running. I am not doing this though - this is simply an app in development that I am debugging as I make changes that do not work. As an aside - I have tracked the issue further and edited the post while you were replying. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The app will end whenever you change any code though, this is pretty standard. If you run under IIS and drop a new .dll into the bin folder you'll find the exact same behaviour - the app pool doesn't recycle but your application will restart because the .NET runtime will reload the appdomain to take account of the new binary.

Comment: The app isn't already running though. It is an app I'm developing and starting/debugging as I make changes that do not work. Shouldn't I be able to make changes to my code, then start/debug using F5 without my app ending, as long as I'm not changing web.config or loading/changing files in app_code etc? This is clearly my misunderstanding regarding the way debug works as I am quite new to .NET - Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @radiator - You're comments are confusing.  Please explain "The app isn't running" while at the same time saying "without my app ending".  How is it ending if it's not running?   Your confusion is that you believe that when you stop debugging, it stops the app, or when you aren't executing a web page, the app isn't running.  It is.  The app is running until the app pool is shut down.  When you make code changes, it reloads the app pool, dumping any session you may have.  The exception to this is when Edit and Continue is enabled, which is not the default.

Comment: Erik - way over my head - what is the app still running on when I end debug? The IIS Express icon disappears from the system tray and, the IIS Express System Tray and worker processes end in task manager.

Comment: @radiator, yes you aren't understanding how .NET works here I'm afraid. If the IIS Express icon is disappearing then your application is definitely being terminated which will absolutely cause the Application_End code to be run. When you start debugging again, you get a brand-new application instance so it will go through the entire lifecycle from scratch (Application_Start etc) and you will lose any Session based information. This is completely normal behaviour and pretty much unavoidable with any compiled language like .NET. PHP or other scripted/interpreted languages are very different.

Comment: Guys - I've added another edit to try and provide clarity. Thanks for bearing with me.